# Python Script Written - GUI options?

Tags: python

I've written a Python script which takes two files, converts one to the same format as the second and outputs the differences.

I now need to create some kind of GUI?

I'm thinking a relatively simple HTML page which allows users to click on two separate boxes to upload each of the files and then submit them - resulting in the output being offered as file which the user can download to the PC.

Any help of direction would be really appreciated. It's only really a guess that HTML will be my best/simplest choice. Working from the command line isn't really an option I can go with. The PC that this will sit on will not have internet access. I intend to have this installed on the PC as an application.

I accept I'll need to make some changes to my Python code.

Comment: using HTML page will need to learn HTML, CSS, maybe JavaScript  and understand how works HTTP protocol and client-server. So it will not so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a solution anyway that will allow you to build a GUI quite easily like [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

A very easy example:

```
import easygui
easygui.msgbox('This is a basic message box.', 'Title Goes Here')
```

Other possibilities (less customizable but arguably easier) are [Wooey](https://github.com/wooey/Wooey) (automatic web interface generation for your script) and [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) (automatic GUI generation for your script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you use the Django Framework for such a small application.

You should definitely use [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) for this. Flask is more lightweight